# Living and working in Turkey and working remotely for a University in Germany

Tags: germany, taxes, contracts

I'm an EU citizen, living and working full time in Turkey. Now, there is a possibility that I could also work remotely for a University in Germany. My question is: Should I pay taxes in Germany for my second job? Has anyone had any experience with how this stuff is handled by the HR departments in Germany? Does this break labor law in Germany?

Comment: What did the university say when you asked?

Comment: @Traveller I have not yet discussed this with HR.